# What is API call limit to jet.com APIs?

Tags: api, jet.com-apis

How many request calls can an API integration make per second to the Jet.com Rest APIs? 
I could not find anything in their documentation on burst size and leak rate(in requests/sec) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Jet Developer team , there isn't any limits on the number of API calls made

Answer (score 0):

There is no API calling limits or throttling in jet.com.
In their later updates , it can be possibility that throtlling will be added.
However, jet.com api is now stable but sometimes it takes long time to update in bulk.